# How to solve this specific props spreading is forbidden Eslint warning

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-props, prop

Beginner question! As the question say How to solve this Prop spreading is forbidden Eslint warning.

Reading the [Eslint doc](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md) on this warning do I really have to do like this:

```
const {dots, arrows, autoplay...........} = props;
```

For all props or is there an easier way?

[image]

```
render() {
    const { afterChanged } = this.props;
    const { beforeChanged } = this.props;
    const settings = {
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: false,
        infinite: true,
        lazyLoad: false,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        centerMode: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        className: 'center',
        slidesToShow: 4,
        afterChange: afterChanged,
        beforeChange: beforeChanged,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: false,
                },
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    initialSlide: 2,
                },
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                },
            },
        ],
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
                {this.sliders()}
            </Slider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eslint just enforces a style you can define yourself. In this case you have to make the decision, whether you want to allow prop spreading in your codebase or not.

-> If you allow it, you should just disable the `react/jsx-props-no-spreading` rule in your eslint config.

-> If you don't allow it, you have to explicitly destructure every property. This is the whole point of that eslint rule. It is made to force you to explicitly name these props, to avoid passing unwanted props down the component tree.